# Mocha error: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have this line of code in my unit testing function with Mocha + Chai:

```
const result = <div>Hello</div>
getHelloDiv().should.be.equal.to(result)
```

But when I run Mocha, I get:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'getHelloDiv().should.be.equal.to(result)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Correcting this:

```
getHelloDiv().should.be.equal.to(result)
```

to this:

```
getHelloDiv().should.equal(result)
```

solved the issue.